# ExtJs4 - Load grid columns dynamically?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I was successfully able to load grid columns dynamically in ExtJs3.
However, I have failed to get it working in ExtJs4.
I can load the columns dynamically but I cannot get them to display in the grid.
When the store loads I build a Column Model, I then set the grids columns as this Column Model. 
After setting the grids columns I tried calling the  `grid.doLayout()` method and also `grid.getView().refresh()` method but the columns are never displayed.
Below is some example code:

```
store.on('load', function(st){
    var columnModel = store.data.items;
    grid.columns = columnModel;
    grid.doLayout();

    /**
      * I also tried doing it this way
      **/
    //grid.getColumnModel().setConfig(columnModel);
    //grid.getView().refresh();
});
```

The grids columns property seems to be getting set correctly but these columns are never displayed.
Just for further clarity the column model which I set as the grids columns property looks like this:

```
[{
    header: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'empname'
},{
    header: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address'
},{
    header: 'Department',
    dataIndex: 'dept'
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the grid columns, you need to call grid.[reconfigure](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure), you cannot just change the columns property. Reconfigure should trigger all the relevant refresh and redisplay events for you.

ergo, your code should read:

```
store.on('load', function(st){
   var columnModel = store.data.items;
   grid.reconfigure(store, columnModel);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. I have been stuck on that for quite a while now. Much appreciated. Regards.

Comment: Just one question regarding the reconfigure method. When i reconfigure the grid with new columns the grids selModel no longer appears on the grid.. Any idea why this is? I have tried adding a new selModel but cannot get it to work?